# Port code scanner I need to be successful?

Tags: c#, console-application, port-scanning

I would like to know how to make an easy port scanner?

How do we please because it doesn't return anything to me! Can you tell me what functions, instructions, loop I should use?

My code is as follows:

```
private static void Scanner()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter IP address");
    string IP = Console.Readline();
    string server = "127.0.0.1"

    IPHostEntry  Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);
    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    foreach(IPAddress ip in Host.AddressList)
    {
        int[] ports = new int [65535];
        for(int i = 1; i < ports.Length; i++) 
        {
            if(s.Connect(ip, ports[i]).Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IP address:" + ip.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Ports:" + ports[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your actual code? This isn't it because it's got a ton of spelling mistakes and syntax errors.

Comment: It's my actual code ! How can I do?

Comment: How does it even compile with names like `AdressFamily`, which is spelled correctly as `AddressFamily`? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.addressfamily?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains all zeroes, but really you have no need for it anyway.

Just do

```
for(int i = 1; i < 65535; i++) 
{
  s.Connect(ip, i);
...
```

Comment: For the record, this is the correct answer and therefore should be accepted. The OP is just iterating over an array of zero elements, rather than incrementing a value on each loop cycle.